# removeObserver not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have next code:

```
@implementation SplashViewVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.splashView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
    self.activityIndicator.originY = 355.f;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NCDownloadComplete object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *n){
        NSInteger errorCode = [n.userInfo[@"errorCode"] integerValue];        
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        if (errorCode == ERROR_CODE_NO_CONNECTION) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Some problem with server" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"try again" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        } else if (errorCode == 0) {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];
    [self downloadData];
}

- (void)downloadData
{
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [[Server sharedServer] getMovieData];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self downloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

@end
```

So I put breakpoints in begin of `viewDidLoad` method, in `viewDidDisappear`. When I launch app that first go to `viewDidload`, after downloading it is go to `viewDidDisappear`.

But during my app I again download data and post `notification: NSDownloadComplete`. And in this VC it is work, but I removed later using:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```

This VC use `viewDidLoad` once in the beginning & can not again addObserver.

What is wrong?

**EDIT**
I try put addObserver method to `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear` - no results.
I add `NSLog(@"addObserver");` before

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName...
```

in viewDidLoad

and write

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"removeObserver");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

In log I see:

```
2013-06-10 14:32:05.646 myApp[9390:c07] addObserver
2013-06-10 14:32:06.780 myApp[9390:c07] removeObserver
```

What wrong?

**EDIT 2**
you can see that observer must be removed but it again run block in addObserver method

[image]

Comment: Is that code copy&pasted? I just wondered because your `viewDidLoad` is just 3 lines and after that there are statements which are not in any method. That's not valid ;)

Comment: @HAS all work fine, except my question =)

Comment: Sorry, but that ain't be ;) The curly brace after `self.activityIndicator.originY = 355.f;` is wrong. Remove and you'll have valid code ;)

Comment: @HAS i edit, mistake, sorry

Comment: Only removeObserver in dealloc

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apart from add/remove observer calls not properly being balanced, at noted in the other answers, there is another problem.

Your code to remove the observer is wrong. For a block-based observer, the *return value* of `addObserver` must be given as argument to `removeObserver`. So you should add a property

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) id observer;
```

to the class. Then you add the observer with

```
self.observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NCDownloadComplete object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *n){
    // ...
}];
```

and remove it with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.observer];
```

Comment: thanks you so much Martin, your solution works so well.

Answer (score 5):

What e1985 is trying to expose is that your `addObserver` and `removeObserver` calls are not properly balanced. `viewDidLoad` is called only once after the VC initialization, but `viewDidDisappear` is called each time the view controller is moved off screen.

To resolve your issue you must balance your `addObserver` and `removeObserver` calls, either by making them in `viewDidLoad` and the other in `dealloc`, or - as e1985 suggested - in `viewDidAppear:` and `viewDidDisappear:`.

**EDIT**: Ok, so your problem comes from the fact that you are using `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` which do not register `self` as observer (as `addObserver:selector:name:object:` would do if you pass `self` as first argument).

So in your case, `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` does nothing because `self` is not an observer. You should instead call `removeObserver:` on the return value of `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`, as shown [in the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-SW1):

> **Return Value**
>
> An opaque object to act as the observer.

So your code should looks something like:

```
// header file .h
@interface SplashViewVC : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id downloadCompleteObserver;

@end

// implementation file .m
@implementation SplashViewVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // [...] snip

    self.downloadCompleteObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NCDownloadComplete object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *n){
        NSInteger errorCode = [n.userInfo[@"errorCode"] integerValue];        
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        if (errorCode == ERROR_CODE_NO_CONNECTION) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Some problem with server" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"try again" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        } else if (errorCode == 0) {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];
    [self downloadData];
}

// [...] snip

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.downloadCompleteObserver];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I move in viewDidAppear: and no results =(

Comment: Please explain the problem more clearly then. What is "not working" ?

Comment: i add screen where you can see that block called after removeObserver method.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you are using is not correct. You should add the observer in `viewDidAppear:` and remove it in `viewDidDisappear:`.

Comment: or add the observer in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: @e1985 don't help. And viewWillAppear: don't help too