# ARC not working properly when using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

Why doesn't deist get called on an object that has used NSNotificationCenter, I have included below a simple version of my code. Where I create an object that observes for a notification and when the notification is fired, it removes the observer's subscription. I also remove the subscription if the object is freed up. However, when running profiling for the app, you can see that after viewDidAppear finishes there is a persistent allocation for the test object that is now nil and should have been freed up. Why is this the case?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var t: test?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        t = test()
        fire()
        t = nil
    }

    func fire() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Hello",
            object: nil)
    }

}

class test {

    var e: NSObjectProtocol?

    init() {
        e = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
            "Hello", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
            usingBlock: sayHello)
    }
    deinit {
        if let e = e { NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(e) }
    }

    func sayHello(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let e = e { NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(e) }
    }

}
```

I would appreciate an answer even in Objective-C, since it will probably answer this question as well.

Thank you very much

Comment: I will open you America: There is no garbage collector in IOS. And in OS X not long time ago.

Comment: Check the return type of `addObserverForName`, so not `self` is the observer in this case. And I think you should use `[weak self]` when you pass in  the closure to the notification center in order not to have a retain cycle.

Comment: You don't remove the observer correctly. The Objective-C version of your question (with answer) is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022714/removeobserver-not-working.

Comment: Add `e = nil` in `sayHello`

Comment: Might be because self is retained in your sayHello block. You should use [weak self] or [unowned self]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing in a function of `self` as a closure parameter will create a retain cycle.
What you're doing is effectivity short hand for:

```
init() {
   e = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("Hello", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() { notification in 
      self.sayHello(notification) 
   }
}
```

As you can see `self` is being captured here. To get around this you should defined `self` as `unowned` in a [capture list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57):

```
init() {
   e = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("Hello", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() { [unowned self] notification in 
      self.sayHello(notification) 
   }
}
```

This will prevent the retain cycle.

As you're removing the observer in `sayHello` you should also set `e` to `nil` in there too after removing the observer.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250524/retain-cycles-when-using-addobserverfornameobjectqueueusingblock) question for more info about retain cycles, capturing, etc. when using this method on `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Thanks this works great, @Rich is there a way to pass a function with weak or unowned captured context? to avoid using closures like in ur example and keep the function

Comment: You could look at [Weakify](https://github.com/klundberg/Weakify), but otherwise no there is not annoyingly!

Answer (score 0):

you don't add self as observer but another block.

BUT

Then you remove yourself (though never added) but forget the block

--- so:

```
self.observer = center.addObserverForName(didEnterBackground, object: nil, queue: nil) {
   ...
}
```

then later

```
center.removeObserver(self.observer)
```